# custom Backbone.View undelegateEvents(), how it works?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

You can implement a custom `delegateEvents()` and `undelegateEvents()` in a Backbone view.

The Backbone.View constructor calls delegateEvents automatically. I thought that undelegateEvents was called when you remove the view with Backbone.View.prototype.remove, but it is not true.

So, which is the best way to do this manually? I have overridden the `remove()` view method with this code:

```
Backbone.View.prototype.remove = function() {
    var remove = Backbone.View.prototype.remove;

    if (this.undelegateEvents) {
      this.undelegateEvents();
    }

    return remove.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

It works, but I don't know if is the best option. How should I do this?

Comment: Why would you need to call `undelegateEvents` if you're removing the view's `el` from the DOM? The `delegate` is attached to the view's `el` so just removing the `el` is sufficient.

Comment: You could also create a base `View` class (extended from Backbone.View) which overrides the default `remove()` method (with essentially the code you've written above). Then, all other views you have would extend the base view instead of Backbone.View. This way, you wouldn't have to override default Backbone behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As mu is too short suggested, the real answer to the question

> which is the best way to do this manually?

is don't.  Events are bound to DOM elements, and if those elements go away so do the bindings.    `undelegateEvents` is designed to be used in situations where you *aren't* removing the DOM element, but still want to take the event bindings off of it (eg. when you set a new element for the view).

Comment: I know. But you can use `undelegateEvents()`to manually remove all configured event delegations. In Backbone documentation -> [Change log](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog): _Added an undelegateEvents to views, allowing you to manually remove all configured event delegations._ My question is... where and how can I use undelegateEvents to do it?

Comment: Anytime, anywhere you want; you may be you're over-thinking this.  You can even do it the one time you specifically asked about (when removing a view) ... there's just no point.  If you want to do it any other time, you just call `yourView.undelegateEvents();`.   And just so there's no mystery, here's the sum total of what `undelegateEvents` actually does: `this.$el.unbind('.delegateEvents' + this.cid);` In other words, remove all event bindings that came from this view from this view's element.